# Calculating countdown between now and x amount of days ahead to cetain time of day

Tags: php, time

I am completely stuck here. I am trying to get how many days hours and minutes to echo from a calculation from the current time to 7 days from now at 6pm. I look at the amount of seconds produced from my $difference variable and when I do the math to convert it to days hours and minutes it is correct but for some reason when I call the specific days, hours, and minutes in my output statement it is incorrect. What am I doing wrong. Here is the code.

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
$nextWeek = strtotime('+7 days');
$m = date('n', $nextWeek);
$d = date('j', $nextWeek);
$y = date('Y', $nextWeek);
$difference = mktime(18,0,0,$m,$d,$y) - time();


echo '<p>Current date and time is' .date(' l F d, Y '). 'at '.date('g:i a').' You have an appointment in a week on '.date(' n/j/Y ', $nextWeek).' at 6pm. There are ' .date(' j ', $difference).' days, ' .date(' g ', $difference).' hours, and ' .date(' i ', $difference).' minutes until your appointment.</p>';

echo mktime(18,0,0,$m,$d,$y),"\n";
echo $difference;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using PHP's `date()` function on a number that doesn't represent a *date*. Your variable `$difference` represents the difference between the two dates, in seconds. To get the right output, you should write your own function to convert these seconds to number of days, hours, minutes, etc.

It might look something like this:

```
function getTimeText($seconds)
{
    $return = array();

    $return["days"] = floor($seconds/86400); // 86400 seconds in a day
    $seconds -= ($return["days"]*86400);

    $return["hours"] = floor($seconds/3600); // 3600 seconds in an hour
    $seconds -= ($return["hours"]*3600);

    $return["minutes"] = floor($seconds/60); // 60 seconds in a minute

    return $return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks everyone. Travesty3 you were correct. My problem was I was thinking wrongly about the use of time() and when I realized that I needed to convert the seconds to days, hours, and minutes. This is what I came up with that seems to do the job. Tell me if you see any flaws with this.

Comment: `<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
$nextWeek = strtotime('+7 days');
$m = date('n', $nextWeek);
$d = date('j', $nextWeek);
$y = date('Y', $nextWeek);
$difference = mktime(18,0,0,$m,$d,$y) - time();
$days = (int)($difference/86400);
$remainder1 = $difference % 86400;
$hours = (int) ($remainder1/3600);
$remainder2 = $remainder1 % 3600;
$mins = (int) (ceil($remainder2/60));`

Comment: `echo '<p>Current date and time is<b>' .date(' l F d, Y '). '</b>at <b>'.date('g:i a').'</b> You have an appointment in a week on <b>'.date(' n/j/Y ', $nextWeek).'</b> at 6pm. There are <b>' .$days. '</b> days, <b>' .$hours.'</b> hours, and <b>' .$mins.'</b> minutes until your appointment.</p>';
?>`

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with it. Looks to me like it works just fine. I do recommend putting that into a function and saving it, though. There's a good chance you'll need it again someday.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking out [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php). The example part way down the page shows you how to find the difference between two dates in days. You should be able to use it to return the difference between the current time and the time in 7 days at 18:00 by changing the format.